# Is it right to use a delegate as a callback after some asynchronous operation?

Tags: c#, delegates

For instance... if i have a method that performs some asynchronous operation and i want to notify/call some sort of callback once it's done, would i use delegate?

I can't seem to get my head round how that would work.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I was looking at something like....

```
public class ContentContext
{
        public delegate void SuccessCallback(Dictionary<String, String> content);

        public void DoSomeAsyncOpertaion(SuccessCallback successCallback)
        {
            //do something and then fire the callback
        }
}
```

But something about that smells funny.  Still a beginner with this c# stuff so forgive my ignorance ;)

Cheers
J

Comment: that's perfectly correct IMHO...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks fine to me. Though you could save yourself the delegate declaration and just use Action<>

I believe the [official pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc(loband).aspx) is to use [IAsyncResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult(loband).aspx), so I'd recommend that if you were developing a frameowrk.

Answer (score 2):

It's ok but the callback will be called on the same thread as the asynchronous operation.

If this is an issue, get some informations about Threads in .Net, [SynchronizationContext](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/SyncContextTutorial.aspx), BackgroundWorder...

Answer (score 0):

I think that's ok. You can also use the [`AsyncCallback` Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.asynccallback.aspx).